# Modify metadata programmatically (of .net executable)

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, il, roslyn

I want my application to be able to modify the metadata of a .net executable. Is there a .net class to do that, or do I have to parse the executable? (Can Roslyn be of any help here?)

If I need to parse the exe - What is its format? I searched, but only came up with [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#.NET.2C_metadata.2C_and_the_PE_format).

Comment: Have a look at Mono/Xamarin. They have a library that allows you to modify IL executables, including changing the code itself programmatically.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks. But I really prefer no 3rd party code. That's why I wrote `.net class`.

Comment: There is no built in way. Use Mono.Cecil. if you don't prefer it roll your own.

Comment: .NET BCL gives you ways to read the data and code, but IMO not anything to modify it. Is it really that much trouble to use one small library that's owned by Microsoft anyway nowadays? After all, you were talking about Roslyn, which is not a part of the BCL either :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `roll your own` - that's fine - but then I need the answer to the second part of the question. I can't seem to find the documentation for an exe's format.

Comment: As for the close vote, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for example.

Comment: @ispiro Answer for second part : Too broad also asking for off site resource is off topic.

Comment: @Luaan I didn't know Xamarin is MS today. I'll look into that. As for the second part - in which way is this off-topic? `off-site resource are off-topic` because, as is stated there: `they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam`. I don't think this applies here. Besides, there's the first part of the question.

Comment: Personally I think the close voting is a bit harsh. This is certainly on topic for SO, and you can't blame the OP for being too broad when he's not sure where to start. This is one of the more interesting questions for the day.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm not looking for `resources` - the `docs` would be splendid. I'd like to "read the fine manual".

Comment: I don't think you can find very comprehensive documentation. [This may help little](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/03/15/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/). Keep in mind you're talking about fairly complex topic which itself a huge project(Reflector, ILSpy) does half of what you're talking about.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. That looks like interesting and helpful reading. (Though I assume there _should_ be some comprehensive documentation _somewhere_.)

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why can't you depend on 3rd party? I've use `Mono.Cecil` successfully. It is very useful and trying to implement it on my own is a nightmare. Also to quote. *Don't reinvent the wheel*.

Comment: And note that ILSpy does in fact use `Cecil`, and it's still a huge project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I need to parse the exe - What is its format?

The format is specified in [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), which describes the [Common Language Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure). But it's over 400 pages, you don't want to implement a reader/writer for all of that yourself. If you really do, you should probably start with [the section that describes the file header (§II.25)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#page=303).

Answer (score 2):

There are no .NET classes that allow you to rewrite IL.

You'll have to choose between using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) or reading [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) and then writing your own IL rewriter. (It's technically possible, after all JB Evain wrote Mono.Cecil almost entirely by himself).

Mono.Cecil's source is available in full on [Github](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).

Basics on Mono.Cecil's usage maybe found in [its wiki](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/HOWTO).